# Giving up on Google Drive API - Server to Server oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, drive

Just as I thought that I "hacked" this ... I realize that I don't understand it anyway.
Important note:
I want to use "server-to-server approved" access so I can avoid Google's crazy approval nightmare for all operations on google drive. My users hate having to approve the script actions on every new copy of my master spreadsheet that we create.

I am trying to use DriveV3 - gem 'google-api-client', '0.9.11'
And I am trying to get authentication working.
I have managed all the initial setup of both console.xxx.xx and admin.google.xxx 
So now I have a .p12 file with a Server-to-server approved credentials.

The following code has been used to get a service:

```
def self.service_client
  keypath = Rails.root.join('config','xxxxxxxx.p12').to_s

  @client = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
  @client.client_options.application_name = "Rails2"

  @client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', :scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    :issuer => "rails2@autoa-automations.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    :signing_key => Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(keypath, "yyyy"))
  @client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

end
```

I did this in my before_filter:

```
session[:google_token] = GoogleDrive::GoogleDocs.service_client
```

And then use it something like ...

def list_google_docs
    gtoken = session[:google_token]
    google_session = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
    google_session.authorization = gtoken
    @google_docs = []

```
page_token = nil
begin
  (myfiles, page_token) = google_session.list_files(page_size: 10, q: "'MYROOTFOLDERID' in parents", fields: 'files(id, mimeType, name), nextPageToken')
  #for file in google_session.drive.list_files(page_size: 10, fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, mime name)')
  myfiles.files.each do |file|
    filename = file.name
    if filename.include?('body')
      @google_docs << filename
    end
  end

end while page_token
```

end

But I keep getting

dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

It worked initially ...
Anyone who can help?
I simply don't get the hole Google authentication approach ... I have tried a lot but this is too complicated for me ...

Comment: What is the role of the service account you are using? Owner, Editor Viewer?

Comment: You might have guided me in a correct direction - I had not added any roles!
I will work more with my code - and get back tomorrow.

Comment: Didn't get it to work ... Seems to have gotten credantials to work ...

This seems to work:

    myauth = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      json_key_io: StringIO.new(File.read('config/autoakey.json')),
      scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    )
    gsess = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
    gsess.client_options.application_name = 'Rails2'
    gsess.authorization = myauth
    gsess.authorization.fetch_access_token!

 but when I do the gsess.list_files .... I get no response!

Comment: Got it to WORK!! It turns out that I read a lot regarding the "console.google.xxx" site and that you need to remember to add the service account to the admin.google.com security page (under safety - go to administration of API-clientaccess). 
I had done this ... but here is MY clue that fixed everything:
Even though I had access to the domain. I still needed to add the service account email to the "share" menu of the folders I wanted to look into:
xxxxxautomations.iam.gserviceaccount.com ... when I added this ... suddenly my list_files started to return files as expected. 
Stupid me ;-)

Comment: good thing you got it working

Comment: Couldn't really understand that I approved unlimited access to the domain - but then still had to add the manual strange email to the folders. But I think it's all about "safety first" ;-)